# writing junit test for spring security login with database user

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit

Hello I am trying to write test for spring user login.

Basically my program uses registration where user provides username, password and email to register to database. Then with registered username and password you can log in to application.

```
 public AuthenticationResponse login(LoginRequest loginRequest) {
        try{
            Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getUsername(),
                    loginRequest.getPassword()));
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            return AuthenticationResponse.builder()
                    .token(jwtProvider.generateToken(authentication))
                    .refreshToken(refreshTokenService.generateRefreshToken().getRefreshToken())
                    .expiresAt(Instant.now().plusMillis(jwtProvider.getJwtExpirationInMillis()))
                    .build();

        } catch (BadCredentialsException e){
            throw new AuthException("Incorrect username or password");
        }
    }
```

But I cant figure out how to write spring boot junit5 test for login. First time I am trying to write these spring tests. Where do I need start?

Answer (score 0):

- You can write unit test by mocking every dependency and check if correct methods were called with verify()
- You can create test with spring context up, and just mocking db layer, then you'll be able to test more then one class
- You can create test with spring context but instead of mocking db layer you can stub your db layer (implement dao which will use cache). This way you can insert user into cache and during testing login you will return that user from cache
- Same as above but using h2 database
- Same as above but using test containers which will start docker image of your actual database. Then you will be able to test whole flow with db constraints